# Make a module available for every file in a python project

Tags: python, directory, pygame, python-import

I'm trying to make a (first) game with Pygame, and I'm stuck on sharing a module across my entire project.

My project tree looks like that:

- Project/

  - main.py (need to import settings.py)
  - settings.py
  - objects/

    - _ *init* _.py
    - player.py (need it too)
  - other dir/

    - other file (and again)

I have a settings.py file that contains hardcoded constants (GRAVITY, PLAYER_SPEED etc...) 
It's needed by a lot of other files, where can I place it so that it's accessible from anywhere in the code?

I tag pygame even if it's not really related as it's a problem that pygame users may have already had.

Comment: Place them in on folder, use `import settings,player,__init__` in your `main.py`and so on.

Comment: It's not sufficient, I need to import them from player.py too, which I can't if it's in the Project folder

Comment: Yes, you can, you just need to add your parent directory to the python path, using the `sys.path.append()` directive.

Comment: Nice, I will try this

Comment: @toti08 It works, thanks ! :)

Comment: @toti08 You should post that as an answer, and the OP can accept it, since they've said it solved the problem.

Comment: I will, as soon as I'll be back on my computer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up what solved the problem: if you want to import the `settings` file from any child folder (`objects` or `other dir`) you should first add the parent directory to the python path using the `sys.path.append` directive:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import settings
```

In this way python will also look into the parent directory for modules to import.

Comment: Sorry, viewed the answer really long later O-:

Comment: But still, exactly what I was seeking, so Thanks !